# Find the Max Value along with the time in Grafana

Tags: grafana

How to find the max value and when it is reached the max value in the particular selected range in grafana.

Let's say,

Here i have graphs for cpu utilization over the last 30 minutes. I want to find out max value and when it is occurred ,

Expected output:

```
Time                         max value
  
2023-03-05 01:03:23          90%
```

Answer (score 1):

Add panel with your query

then go to `Transform` tab and add `Sort by` transformation

Select your field with value

Toggle `Reverse` to `true`

Add Limit transformation with `Limit = 1`
[image]